# Angular Routing to External Page OnClick

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, routes

I have built a application where I have a standalone component that acts as a submenu, taking as one of it's fields a array of objects. The menu works fine as long as the routes are internal, but when I attempt to pass a external url, the route goes to the page on load instead of waiting for the user to click to go.

Main file:

```
<submenu [data]=data></submenu>

url = `${ENDPOINT}files/`;

public data = [
{
title: 'Files',
url: '/files',
active: true,
},
{
title: 'Storage',
url: window.open(this.url, '_blank'),
active: false,
},
]
```

Component:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
<a [routerLink]="item.url" routerLinkActive="active"></a>
</li>

@Input() data : any[];
url;

this.subs.sink = this.router.events.subscribe((link: any) => {
   if (link instanceof NavigationEnd) {
     const activeLink = find(this.data, {url: link.url});
     if (!isNil(activeLink)) {
        this.data = map(this.data, (page) => merge(page, {active: false}));
        activeLink.active = true;
      }
    }
});
```

Endpoint is just a basic url that changes based on the environment, like dev or test.

Goal is that the url window.open(`${ENDPOINT}files/`) routes to the external url in a new page when the user clicks on the menu item instead of it being loaded right when the page loads.

Currently the external url loads right when the page with the submenu loads and opens in a new tab, but when you go back to the page with the submenu, if you click on the menu button, nothing occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If the above code is your original code there are some issues there.

```
{
  title: 'Storage',
  url: 'window.open(this.url, "_blank"),
        active: false,
},
```

1. The opening quotes at the start of the url property is not closed
2. You should not used window.open instead just the url
3. Since you want to open the url in new tab if it is an external url, use a logic (if title is 'Storage' or active is false) and add **target="_blank"** attribute in the anchor tag instead.

Please mark it as answer if it helps. Happy Coding :)